# I want to sort duplicate values from an array like below

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to sort duplicate values from an array like below:

```
Array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
```

I want an output like below:

```
[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,5]
```

Comment: Did you at least try `sort`?

Comment: ya i was but not getting relevant o/p.

Comment: `sort` will definitely work for you, `Array.sort` output = `# => [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]`

Comment: Based on the accepted answer and taking a hard look at your example, are you by any chance trying to sort the array by the number of times an element appears in it? For instance, your input has 4 1s -> 3 2s -> 2 3s -> 1 5....so if you added 5 6s into your array `[1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]` the expected output would be `[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]`? (the accepted answer doesn't do this, but it would explain why `sort` isn't giving the relevant o/p)

Answer (score 1):

> Sort duplicate values from an array.

Returns a new array created by sort. Comparisons for the sort will be done using the **<=> operator**.

```
Array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
Array.sort
# => [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
```

You can use `Array.sort!` as well.

Comment: You should explain why `Array` is not a good name for the constant here (e.g, we would get `Array.class #=> Array` when we wanted `Array.class #=> Class`, `Array` being the class whose instances are arrays).

Comment: **Have you look at the question**, I know what is an `Array`, I use same as a question for his understanding.

Comment: I'm just suggesting (not criticising) that you expand your answer (which is fine) to explain to the OP why his choice of `Array` for the name of a constant is not a good idea. Also, I'm not sure if he is aware that `Array` is a constant and not a variable, so you might want to say a few words about that as well. If it we're me I'd just write `arr.sort` and then explain why I used `arr` rather than `Array` or `Arr`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, Your opinion absolutely right, but the person who even don't know what is the difference between above two answers. How can I assume that he is ready for my explanation? I am agreed with you.